# Saving a curl response into a php variable

Tags: php, curl, amazon-ec2

I am trying to access my ec2's public hostname from inside the instance.

I would like to run this command

```
curl http:// 169 254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-hostname
```

inside a php script and save the response to a variable.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**You can do like this**

```
<?php  
//URL of targeted site  
$url = "http://www.yahoo.com/";  
$ch = curl_init();  

// set URL and other appropriate options  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  

// grab URL and pass it to the browser  

$output = curl_exec($ch);  

//echo $output;

// close curl resource, and free up system resources  
curl_close($ch);  
?>
```

The `$output` variable contains the response.

Comment: This worked for me. The only change I made was the url. Not sure what that other comment was all about.

Answer (score 14):

Shankar Damodaran provided an example of how to retrieve the response from a curl request, but specifically it is the

[`CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER`](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/CURL_PHP_tutorial) that does as it says and returns the result from `curl_exec`