# How to retrieve a specific value from a RESTful response using curl

Tags: php, rest, curl

I want to get the **name** value from the below RESTful response

```
{
"login": "mdo",
"id": 98681,
"url": "https://api.github.com/users/mdo",
"html_url": "https://github.com/mdo",
"type": "User",
"site_admin": true,
"name": "Mark Otto",
"company": "GitHub",
"blog": "http://mdo.fm",
"location": "San Francisco, CA",
}
```

Here is my code. So far, I have only manage to retrieve the complete result.

```
<?php
//step1
$cSession = curl_init(); 
//step2
curl_setopt($cSession, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:17.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/17.0');
curl_setopt($cSession,CURLOPT_URL,"https://api.github.com/users/mdo");
curl_setopt($cSession,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($cSession,CURLOPT_HEADER, false); 
//step3
$result=curl_exec($cSession);
//step4
curl_close($cSession);
//step5
echo $result;
?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Saving a curl response into a php variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16338174/saving-a-curl-response-into-a-php-variable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) method like so:

```
$obj = json_decode($result); 

echo $obj->{'name'};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works like a charm. Also learned about the explicit use of curly braces.

Answer (score 1):

You can first decode your result with `json_decode` using below statement.

```
$arr = json_decode($result, true);
```

And then you can access name via `$arr['name'];`

```
echo $arr['name'];
```

It's very simple, Try out this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.